# Copy an entire DevExpress.XtraTreeList.TreeList in C#

Tags: c#, treeview, backgroundworker

The scenario:

I am creating and populating a Treelist using a database.

This is a rather time-consuming task, and don't want to hang the gui (nor have any "progress-bar" etc).

So I decided to move all this to a Backgroundworker, but since I cant update the tree from another thread then the one who created it I am creating a temp-tree in the background-thread and when done, just copy the entire contents to the GUI-shown tree.

1. What is the best way to traverse and copy all nodes, node-data etc?
2. Is there another (better?) way to do this, ie build/create a tree in a Backgroundworker and showing it in the GUI?

Edit: I am aware of the 'hack' of populating a GUI component in a background-thread, but since I just got thrown into this project and asked to "stop the gui from hanging quite often" with a very limited time frame, re-writing the loading and creation of the data is not really an option (even though this would ofc be the best practice).
I just changed the "CreateTree"-function to run in a new thread, pass the newly created tree to "ThreadComplete" and copy it.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

UI elements, like a TreeView, should stay in the UI end of things. There are technical reasons for this - Windows doesn't allow updating UI elements from any threads but the main UI threads - but also architectural reasons: your back-end DB-accessing code shouldn't be tightly coupled to any specific UI implementation. If you decide to switch from TreeList to a different control, by DevExpress or any other vendor, you'll have to replace code all through your system.

What you want to do is have your back-end code create a more general data structure, like a list of business objects with a hierarchical structure, like this:

```
public class MyBusinessObject
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<MyBusinessObject> ChildObjects {get;}
}
```

and return a list of `MyBusinessObject` from your background thread. This list should be connected to your TreeList using databinding. You didn't specify what UI platform you're using - XtraaTreeList is a WinForms control, right? - but all common frameworks have databinding options to bind this list of business objects to the UI control, rather than have you do all the work yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update a Component from another thread, you can use a [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) and then traverse it like it's in the same thread.